# Opacity Color Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm building a dataframe with Pandas. I know I can change a row background color with a simply function:

```
def row_style(row):

    if row.Foo ==0:
        return pd.Series('background-color: green', row.index)
    
    else:
        return pd.Series('background-color: red', row.index)

df.style.apply(row_style, axis=1)
```

But I couldn't find where to change its opacity. It would be useful because this standard color looks solid and ugly.

Comment: Can't you use any hex rgb value instead of 'red', 'green' etc?

Comment: I actually don't know. My source of knowledge is https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html and it says nothing about RGB or HEX there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use rgba (max of alpha value is 1)

example

```
background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.2)
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Define the Opacity.

If you don't care to figure out different colors, or just need different opacity within the same color you can add that property to the styler: chain it on with a ';'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Foo': [0,1,2,0], 'Bar': [1,2,3,4]})

def row_style(row):
    if row.Foo == 0:
        return pd.Series('background-color: green; opacity: 0.5' , row.index)
    else:
        return pd.Series('background-color: red; opacity: 0.5', row.index)

df.style.apply(row_style, axis=1)
```

[image]

---

#### Define better colors

The opacity also affects the text (no such thing as just background-opacity), so it is not the greatest. Instead look for better colors. There are a bunch of websites that will provide you with the hex or rgb codes for good color pallettes. [iWantHue](https://medialab.github.io/iwanthue/) is the one I use.

```
def row_style(row):
    if row.Foo == 0:
        return pd.Series('background-color: #5eae76' , row.index)
    else:
        return pd.Series('background-color: #de796e', row.index)

df.style.apply(row_style, axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: What a great answer! Thank you.

Comment: By the way, using background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.2), such as the other answer, does not affect the text opacity.

Comment: @momba yes, the other answer is very good and simple :D, probably should accept that over this one.